# How can I specify an unbounded wildcard type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, unbounded-wildcard

I couldn't event choose right words for the question.

I have a class and a factory method.

```
class MyObject<Some, Other> {

    static <T extends MyObject<U, V>, U, V> T of(
            Class<? extends T> clazz, U some, V other) {
        // irrelevant 
    }

    private Some some;

    private Other other;
}
```

Now I want to add two more factory methods each which only takes `U` or `V`.

That would be look like this. That means those omitted `V`, or `U` remains unset(`null`).

```
static <T extends MyObject<U, ?>, U> T ofSome(
        Class<? extends T> clazz, U some) {
    // TODO invoke of(clazz, some, @@?);
}

static <T extends MyObject<?, V>, V> T ofOther(
        Class<? extends T> clazz, V other) {
    // TODO invoke of(clazz, @@?, other);
}
```

I tried this but not succeeded.

```
static <T extends MyObject<U, ?>, U> T ofSome(
        final Class<? extends T> clazz, final U some) {
    return of(clazz, some, null);
}
```

Compiler complains with following message.

> no suitable method found for of(java.lang.Class,U, <nulltype>)

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Please show the exact code : you don't declare return types in some of your methods. As a side note, in your first class U and V are distinct types according to the scope : class or instance since you declare it twice.

Comment: Try casting `null` to the required type, EG: `(V) null`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need the generic parameter `V`, you just don't need the method parameter `V`.

```
static <T extends MyObject<U, V>, U, V> T ofSome(
        final Class<? extends T> clazz, final U some) {
    return of(clazz, some, null);
}
```

You need `V` in `ofSome` so that the compiler can infer the `V` type for `of` by looking at the type of `clazz`.